# App is not visible in Google Play and even on direct link for the app is not working

Tags: android, google-play

My app doesn't display in Google Play Market.
I've published the through Developer Console.
But the app is not visible even on https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=not.visible.app (it is fake package just to illustrate the problem)

Not sure why it doesn't work. Here is my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="not.visible.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/Fake">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainMenuActivity"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>
</application>
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you Publishing your application after upload apk file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll take a few hours up to a day till your App is shown in the Market. When have you uploaded it?

Comment: Around 2 hours. I supposed that it should be displayed immediately by direct link, no?

Comment: I mean in the link like this:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=not.visible.app

Comment: No. I had the same issue with my first App. It took a few hours. But then it worked fine. Also when I upload an update there comes a message that it takes a few hours till the new version is in the market and the users are informed.

Comment: In my case, it takes about 20h but my app is still not visible in Google Play (via search or direct link). Should I continue waiting?

Comment: Is your device compatible with your app? Because if it is not it won't be shown anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if it is required, but you should put the screen support on your manifest, for example:

```
<supports-screens android:normalScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"></supports-screens>
```

But to see you app on the playstore you should wait 2/3 hours.

Comment: I haven't spizified the supportet screens and in the App info in the market stands `Screen layouts: small, normal, large, xlarge`. So I think that it is only needet when you want to exclude some screen types.